# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist : jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, weblogic, jdbctemplate

We are using jdbc template for communicating with oracle database in our project and after deployment it is throwing following exception.

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select count(*) from users
>   where temp_id = ?]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

Table **users** already exist in the table still it is throwing RA-00942: table or view does not.

Following is the java code

> this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from
>   users where temp_id = ?", new Object[] {userKey}, Integer.class);

Where userKey is a String passed as an argument in the method

What could be the probable reason behind this exception?

Edit : After updating query

> this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from
>   dbuser.users where temp_id = ?", new Object[] {userKey}, Integer.class);

still same issue exists

Comment: Are you connected to correct Oracle user?

Comment: How to know that? So is it user related issue?

Comment: In order to connect, you have to provide username, password and database name. So, did you provide these credentials that match the ones that contain the USERS table you're trying to select from?

Comment: Yes I have already provided  username, password and database in the datasource configuration of weblogic server

Comment: Might be issue is because only user with name 'dbuser' has privileges to users table

Comment: Maybe. In that case, DBUSER will have to `GRANT SELECT ON users TO some_other_user;`

Comment: that will not help because we have to strictly use DBUSER  only

Comment: I have tried in this way also  this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from dbuser.users where temp_id = ?", new Object[] {userKey}, Integer.class);

Comment: No idea, sorry. It works if you connect as DBUSER via SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or TOAD or any similar tool. But, how to do it using tools you mentioned as tags for your question - I wouldn't know.

Comment: Aha; well, if you have to use DBUSER, then just make sure that you really ARE connected as DBUSER and it should work.

Comment: If DBUSER has access to other schemas you should prepend the schema of the table. Or just put SCHEMA.USER and try